# Where are my $_FILES? Ajax Uploading

Tags: php, ajax, upload, prototypejs

I've built a form to upload images, and processed with Prototype/PHP.

```
$('image_upload').observe('submit', function() {

     var params = $H();
     params.set('name', $('image_title').value);
     params.set('from', $('from_who').value);
     params.set('upload_file', $('upload_file').value);

     new Ajax.Request('/files/upload_process.php', {
      method:'post',
      parameters: params,

      onSuccess: function(r) {
       $('uploadbox').update('<img src="/images/interface/thankyou.png" />');


      }

     })



    });
```

The form itself sends the data to the server, but when I try to output `print_r($_FILES['upload_file']);` nothing appears, not even an empty array.

If I output `print_r($_POST)`, the parameters are sent properly, but only the file name of the image.

So it seems the files themselves are not being sent along.
How do I handle this?
Thanks
Rich

Comment: For the record, it's possible to upload through AJAX using the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object. The method is easy to use, and currently supported by Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can send files via ajax for security reasons. You'll have to post the form to an iframe and handle it from there.

Comment: Reasons for down vote: Because you beat someone else to the answer, because you didn't provide a complete working solution, or finally just because someone out there can down vote you for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense on the reasons stated here.

Comment: you can in html5: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/uploading-files-with-xmlhttprequest/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use XHR to upload files.
You need either to use an IFRAME or flash/Java and such plugins of the browser.